# Banned emails are still registering to phpBB forum - how could that be?

Tags: spam-prevention, registration, phpbb

I manage a phpBB forum (v3.0.12) and am having a problem with spam registrations. We have CAPTCHA setup and two step verification. The problem is, users are still registering with emails we've explicitly banned upon verifying or entered into the banned email list manually. For example, we'll ban *@spam.spamhost.com and *@spamhost.com and then shortly after and for weeks to follow, we'll continue getting just as many user-verified registrations from user1@spam.spamhost.com, user2@spam.spamhost.com, user3@bots.spamhost.com, etc.

I realize the forum software is out of date but due to customization that was done before I took over, others on the team are hesitant to update it. If that is a likely cause of this issue I can push the point.

What could cause this issue of users being able to register and verify their email, using email domains that are already on our ban list? I've tried digging into the website and online searches to resolve this but have had no luck so far.

Comment: Just to clarify... you say you have supposedly "banned" these email addresses, but your heavily customised phpBB software seems to be ignoring this "banned list"? And you are asking us why that is?

Comment: Right. I'll take that as "figure out _what_ customization happened and if it could impact user registration or ban list effectiveness" - another reason that updating to the latest phpBB could be good as long as we wouldn't lose any critical customization. (I'm not sure how 'heavy' the customization is, since I can't tell what's unique about this phpBB install - aside from ineffective banning.)

Comment: Yeah, something like that, although (I'm no phpBB expert) articles/threads I've read seem to suggest that the "Ban E-mails feature" bans already registered users with that email, it doesn't necessarily prevent those emails from registering in the first place (but I could be wrong about that)???